# Error in named query: UnescalatedDeadlines?

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I am using jPBM 5.4.0 and trying to do the sample project which explained [here](https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/02/27/helloprocess-example-using-jbpm5-eclipse-plug-in).

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.task");
TaskService taskService  = new TaskService(emf,SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener());
```

In second line I am getting this error.

```
Error in named query: UnescalatedDeadlines
org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to render boolean literal value [select new    org.jbpm.task.query.DeadlineSummary( t.id, d.id, d.date) from org.jbpm.task.Task t, org.jbpm.task.Deadline d where (d in elements( t.deadlines.startDeadlines ) or d in elements( t.deadlines.endDeadlines ) ) and d.escalated = false order by d.date]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.. are you sure that you are using the correct version of hibernate? (the one that jBPM needs?)

Are you using MySQL? Which version, because I've found that someone also report that issue: https://community.jboss.org/thread/220651?start=0&tstart=0